# How can I install a door in this opening?

Tags: walls, doors, brick

I want to install a door in a very tall wall opening [image: Opening], this is a brick wall and was originally just a partition wall between 2 apartments.
The dimesions of the opening are 0.65 m wide and 2.5 m tall so I should be able to fit a 60 cm door with a door frame but I'm not sure how to go about lowering the ceiling, I've though 2 ideas:

1. Installing a drywall over the whole wall, I think this would work but It might look bad since to the left of the picture is another door so I can only cover half of the wall
2. Make a drywall header and install it there, only problem is I'm not sure how sturdy it would be since I'd have to attach it to a side stud.

Comment: Go for the 2.5m tall door...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at how other doorframes are built. Use that as a guide to build rough wood framing into this opening, with transom at floor, uprights along each side, a crosspiece to define the top of the door opening. Apply door stop molding, fit door, mortise for hinges and install. In the space above the door, install a suitable panel, nicely trimmed out -- this could be a transom window in the middle (maybe stained or etched glass?), or simply wallboard on each side (if that's your plan, the frame may need to be a bit narrower up here so the wallboard winds up flush with the wall). Apply surface trim to hide the junctions between components and make the framing seem more deliberate/more substantial. Paint or stain as appropriate (you may want to finish the trim before mounting it; easier and reduces risk of making a mess.)

Does that help, or is there something more specific you're asking?